# Проблема с таблицей и её thead, tbody, tfoot

Tags: html

Делаю задание по веб разработке. И то ли баг какой, то ли я недостаточно разобрался в HTML, но задание никак не хочет принимать мой код.

В чем я ошибся?

Само задание:

---

Создать таблицу, которая содержит заголовок, 4 колонки и 2 строки для основной информации, последняя строка как вывод. Во всех клетках заголовка текст "Заголовок", для всех остальных - "Текст".

Образец:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требования:

- Заголовок в тег `<caption>`
- Заголовки колонок в тег `<thead>`
- Основная информация в тег `<tbody>` - две строки
- Вывод в тег `<tfoot>` - последняя строка, разместить после `</tbody>`

Для Выполнение задания скопируйте шаблон в рабочую область и замените комментарий на вашу реализацию.

---

Вот мой код, на котором я и застрял. Жирные буквы для строки с заголовками пробовал делать, ни `<b>`, ни `<strong>` не меняют результат.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>Вивчаємо HTML</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 
    <table>
      <caption>Заголовок таблиці</caption>
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <td>Заголовок</td>
              <td>Заголовок</td>
              <td>Заголовок</td>
              <td>Заголовок</td>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
          <tr>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
              <td>Текст</td>
          </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете выделить заголовок в `th`, а не `td`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><title>Вивчаємо HTML</title>
</head>
<body>


<table>
    <caption>Заголовок таблиці</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
        <td>Текст</td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```